# How can I search folder path on puppet?

Tags: puppet

On a box I got both the x32 and x64 version of the jdk, having the JAVA_HOME pointing to th x64 one.

This is fine most of the time, but there's some programs that need to use the x32 bit jdk. One of these is the GO.CD build agent, which uses a environment variable to do so.

Now the issue is, I need to figure out how to find this path but I don't really know how to find this out through a puppet script (maybe using ruby?).

Hence the question over here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write ruby code to find path and create fact to store value of path.
Assume you are searching for 'jdk1.7_72' folder path on system.
Here is example:

1. Create ruby file under {moudule_name}/lib/facter/jdk_path.rb
2. Copy following content in file:

> require 'facter'
>
> Facter.add(:jdk_path) do
>
> ```
>  setcode do
>         filepath = `find -L / -name "jdk1.7_72*" -type d -print -quit`
>
>         if filepath.to_s.empty? then jdk_path = 'unknown'
>         else
>             jdk_path = filepath
>         end
> end
> ```
>
> end

3. Run puppet on agent(sudo puppet agent --test).
4. Run command on agent 'sudo puppet facter -p jdk_path'.
   Output should be path of jdk.
5. Now you can use variable 'jdk_path' in your puppet code.

Note:

- If you want to pick up first path by default then use command:

  find -L / -name "jdk*" -type d -print -quit
- If want to pick up all paths then use command:

  find -L / -name "jdk*" -type d -print